# jacorb generates .java files incorrectly

Tags: java, jacorb

Given the below IDL file

```
#include <CosNotifyComm.idl>

module TestEvent
{
    typedef CosNotifyComm::SequencePushConsumer Subscriber;  
    typedef CosNotification::StructuredEvent CoreEvent;
};
```

Jacorb (**v3.2**) generates SubscriberHelper class with errors. However CoreEventHelper class is generated correctly.
For example:

> public static void insert (org.omg.CORBA.Any any,
>   CosNotifyComm.SequencePushConsumer s)

The correct code is

> public static void insert (org.omg.CORBA.Any any, org.omg.CosNotifyComm.SequencePushConsumer s)

Is this a bug? How to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody replied, I will answer this question with the workaround that I found.

The jacorb idl to java generator "idl.bat" provides an option -i2jpackage. So you should pass "`-i2jpackage CosNotifyComm:org.omg.CosNotifyComm`" to idl.bat while executing it.

If this is a bug or not, I still dont know.